# In Python format (f-string) strings, what does !r mean?

Tags: python, python-3.6, f-string

I get what the new f strings in python 3.6 do, but what about the ending !r as found in the code snip below.

```
def __repr__(self):
    return (f'Pizza({self.radius!r}, 'f'{self.ingredients!r})')
```

Answer (score 160, accepted):

It just calls the `repr` of the value supplied.

It's usage is generally not really needed with f-strings since with them you can just do `repr(self.radius)` which is arguably more clear in its intent.

`!r` (`repr`), `!s` (`str`) and `!a` (`ascii`) were kept around just to ease compatibility with the `str.format` alternative, you don't need to use them with f-strings.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#s-r-and-a-are-redundant has the detail about '!s', '!r', '!a'

Comment: It isn't that the `!r` does nothing in f-strings, it just seems rarely useful.