# What does !r:<3 mean?

Tags: python, formatting

I was following a tutorial and found this.

```py
print(f"{self.name}: {card!r:<3}  ", end="")
```

And I have no idea what the `!r:<3` means. Google wouldn't give me relevant results because of all the symbols.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python format (f-string) strings, what does !r mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44800801/in-python-format-f-string-strings-what-does-r-mean)

Comment: I found it by searching "python bang r" btw.

Comment: You probably want to look for `!r` and `<3` separately.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be great in this case, but in general: http://symbolhound.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can find a description of the format of f-strings [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) and of the formatting language [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).

`!r:<3` uses `repr` to format the value, left aligned with a minimum width of 3 (padded with spaces by default).