# Python - the meaning of "!"

Tags: python, printing, decorator, wrapper

While studying Python, I run the following example code regarding `function.wrap`.

```py
def trace(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f'{func.__name__}({args!r}, {kwargs!r}) '
              f'-> {result!r}')
        return result
    return wrapper

@trace
def fibonacci(n):
    """Return the n-th Fibonacci number"""
    if n in (0, 1):
        return n
    return (fibonacci(n - 2) + fibonacci(n - 1))

fibonacci(4)
```

In this code,  I don't understand `print (f'{func.__name__} ({args!r}, {kwargs!r}) 'f'-> {result!r}')` in `trace` function.

What does this `!r` mean?

Even without this `!r`, the results are the same.

- Result

```
fibonacci(4)

>>>
fibonacci((0,), {}) -> 0
fibonacci((1,), {}) -> 1
fibonacci((2,), {}) -> 1
fibonacci((1,), {}) -> 1
fibonacci((0,), {}) -> 0
fibonacci((1,), {}) -> 1
fibonacci((2,), {}) -> 1
fibonacci((3,), {}) -> 2
fibonacci((4,), {}) -> 3
```

Comment: Those are conversion flags, you can decide whether to use the `str` or `repr` of an object

Comment: For f-strings specifically, see also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44800801/in-python-format-f-string-strings-what-does-r-mean

Comment: So consider, `print(f"{'foo'!s}")` and `print(f"{'foo!'r}")`