# Issue with sorting list of objects

Tags: python

I'm having trouble sorting a list of objects in Python. I have a list of Person objects, and I want to sort them based on their age. However, the sorting doesn't seem to be working as expected. Here's my code:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

people = [
    Person("Alice", 30),
    Person("Bob", 25),
    Person("Charlie", 40),
    Person("David", 22)
]

sorted_people = sorted(people, key=lambda person: person.age)
print(sorted_people)
```

I expected the output to be a list of `Person` objects sorted by their age, like this:

```
[Person("David", 22), Person("Bob", 25), Person("Alice", 30), Person("Charlie", 40)]
```

However, the actual output I'm getting is:

```
[<__main__.Person object at 0x...>, <__main__.Person object at 0x...>, ...]
```

It seems like the sorting is not working as intended. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this sorting issue?

Comment: As far as we can tell that's working exactly as intended. Your output is a list of Person objects, what's makes you think they're not in the right order?

Comment: Related: [How to print instances of a class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1535327/11082165)

Comment: Did you try printing the list *before* you sorted it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [a `__repr__` implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) to your class to get nice default string representations:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Person({repr(self.name)}, {self.age})'
```

As [Kelly Bundy points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76953306/issue-with-sorting-list-of-objects/76953400?noredirect=1#comment135658417_76953400), you can also use [the `!r` shorthand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44800801/in-python-format-f-string-strings-what-does-r-mean) in the f-string literal to call `repr()` on the member items:

```
class Person:
    # ...
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Person({self.name!r}, {self.age!r})'
```

Comment: Or `f'Person({self.name!r}, {self.age!r})'`

Comment: @KellyBundy I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the `!r` formatting directive

Comment: It calls `repr()`.

Answer (score 0):

The list is probably sorted exactly right!
You are seeing the default representation for a python object.
If you want to see a nicer looking output when printing, look into implementing one of the following "dunder" methods, `__str__()` or `__repr__()`.
A good Tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-str-repr-functions).

It might end up looking something like this:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Name: {self.name} Age: {self.age}'
```